How can I use Gson to unmarshal json into different class instances when data is a string-value map?
A brokerage is returning data from a GET for the query "MSFT,AAPL,XYZZ":
{
  "MSFT": {
    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
    "assetSubType": "COE",
    "quoteType": "NBBO",
    ...lots more
  },
  "AAPL": {
    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
    "assetSubType": "COE",
    "quoteType": "NBBO",
    ...lots more
  },
  "errors": {
    "invalidSymbols": [
      "XYZZ"
    ]
  }
}

The brokerage chose to put errors into its own "errors" entry at the end of the list of good results. I don't see a way to configure GSON to use an errors class for the "errors" value (which itself can be complex and nested).
For now, it's possible to capture all the attributes with one "combination" class:
public static class Quote {
  public String assetMainType;
  public String assetSubType;
  public String quoteType;
  ...
  public List<String> invalidSymbols;
}

java.lang.reflect.Type mapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Quote>>() {
}.getType();
Map<String, Quote> map = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
Quote errors = map.remove("errors");
if (errors != null) {
  // handle unrecognized symbols
}

Is there a way for GSON to use two classes and have the "errors" entry unmarshall to its own class?

There is not a built-in way to do that because your JSON format is non-trivial, and it would require something like injecting a specific type adapter to the default map type adapter under very specific conditions. But you can use type adapters that are designed to extend what Gson does not support.
I assume the following mappings can satisfy your needs (the annotations below are Lombok extensions to generate boilerplate code):
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
final class QuoteError {

    private final List<String> invalidSymbols;

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
final class Quote {

    private final String assetMainType;
    private final String assetSubType;
    private final String quoteType;

}

I would also combine them two into a single pair-like class (it would not be really possible to use a generic "true" pair class, something like Pair<Map<Quote>, Error>, because the generic type adapter should not be responsible for specific cases, just like the Gson Map<K, V> type adapter).
public record ValueMapAndError<V, E>(
        Map<String, V> valueMap,
        E error
) {
}

The record class above then can be deserialized using a type adapter factory (to "parse" types) and a type adapter to read the JSON payload.
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class ValueMapAndErrorTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final String errorKey;

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getInstance(final String errorKey) {
        return new ValueMapAndErrorTypeAdapterFactory(errorKey);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if (!typeToken.getRawType().isAssignableFrom(ValueMapAndError.class)) {
            return null;
        }
        final ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) typeToken.getType();
        final Type valueType = type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        final Type errorType = type.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        final Type valueMapType = TypeToken.getParameterized(Map.class, String.class, valueType).getType();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new Adapter<>(gson, valueMapType, errorType, errorKey);
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private static final class Adapter<V, E> extends TypeAdapter<ValueMapAndError<V, E>> {

        private final Gson gson;
        private final Type valueMapType;
        private final Type errorType;
        private final String errorKey;

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, ValueMapAndError<V, E> valueAndError) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public ValueMapAndError<V, E> read(JsonReader jsonReader) {
            // buffer it in memory entirely using intermediate JSON-representation object  since the type adapter requires two-pass deserialization
            // kind of expensive, so consider implementing field-by-field reading
            final JsonObject outerObjectBuffer = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonObject.class);
            final JsonElement innerObjectBuffer = outerObjectBuffer.remove(errorKey);
            final Map<String, V> valueMap = gson.fromJson(outerObjectBuffer, valueMapType);
            final E error = gson.fromJson(innerObjectBuffer, errorType);
            return new ValueMapAndError<>(valueMap, error);
        }

    }

}

It's a bit complex, but I'm not sure whether it can be simplified. But it can be optimized by removing the buffering read and not keeping probably a large JSON tree map if the errors payload ("error": {...}) is guaranteed to be the last entry in the whole JSON (it would also require a custom Map<String, V> reading and deserializing its values not using the built-in Gson type adapter).
public final class ValueMapAndErrorTypeAdapterFactoryTest {

    private static final ParameterizedType valueMapAndErrorListType = (ParameterizedType) TypeToken.getParameterized(
            ValueMapAndError.class, Quote.class, QuoteError.class
    ).getType();

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(ValueMapAndErrorTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance("errors"))
            .create();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final ValueMapAndError<Quote, QuoteError> quoteMapAndQuoteError = gson.fromJson(
            """
            {
                "MSFT": {
                    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
                    "assetSubType": "COE",
                    "quoteType": "NBBO"
                },
                "AAPL": {
                    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
                    "assetSubType": "COE",
                    "quoteType": "NBBO"
                },
                "errors": {
                    "invalidSymbols": [
                        "XYZZ"
                    ]
                }
            }
            """,
            valueMapAndErrorListType
        );
        System.out.println(quoteMapAndQuoteError.valueMap());
        System.out.println(quoteMapAndQuoteError.error());
    }

Not really a unit test above and I used it only to run the demo, I just guess that dumping the objects to the stdout with their toString methods is fine enough:
{MSFT=Quote(assetMainType=EQUITY, assetSubType=COE, quoteType=NBBO), AAPL=Quote(assetMainType=EQUITY, assetSubType=COE, quoteType=NBBO)}
QuoteError(invalidSymbols=[XYZZ])

